# Transpose Songs To Fit My Vocal Range

Tags: vocal-range

If my vocal range is C2-C4 and I get a song that's C3-C5 should I be looking to transpose the song's range as close to the octave of my vocal range as possible or the pitch? What I mean is would I just simply transpose the song's range down an octave (which falls exactly on my vocal range) or could i just leave it as it is since the pitches of the song's range match my vocal range although they're in a different octave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave the piano accompaniment (or whatever) alone.  It will sound fine when you sing in 'your' octave.

Comment: I'm not sure what it is you're saying. Could you be more clear please?

Comment: Just sing the notes an octave lower than written. Transposing the accompaniment down an octave will probably create a muddy sounding mess. and may be impossible anyway on instruments like guitars. etc.

Comment: I'm still a little confused. What is the accompaniment?

Comment: The accompaniment is the music that someone else--or you--play alongside the melody you're singing. For example, it's the guitar part of Bon Jovi's "Livin' on a Prayer".